# a='01101' this has to be converted to ['0','1','1','0','1'] ?? IN PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

> convert a *binary string* into list in **python**
>   example '10011' is to be converted as **list** ['1','0','0','1','1'] ?

Comment: did you try `list(a)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called list to do this directly.This can convert any string into list of characters.

```
list('01101')
```

will return

```
['0', '1', '1', '0', '1']
```

One more way is

```
a = '01101'
a_list=[]
for item in a:
    a_list.append(item)
print(a_list)
```

Comment: For the second example, why do you need `i`? `for item in a: list.append(item)` would be fine. Also naming a list `list` just shadows the builtin function [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), which is never a good idea.

Comment: @RoadRunner just wondering if `list()` is considered a function. The documentation says *"Rather than being a function, list is actually a mutable sequence type"*, but also includes it in [Built-in functions list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Comment: @Ayxan I guess it can be looked that way. This might be a good question to ask honestly, I'm curious to see what others have to say.

Comment: @RoadRunner asked it. Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53649958/10147399)

Comment: @RoadRunner I didn't give much time to it yesterday.. I taken your inputs.Thank you